# Sum 2-D arrays in Python

Tags: python

I have two 2-D arrays, and I tried to sum element-wise

```
 A = array([[-0.31326169, -0., -3.23995333],
               [-0.26328247, -0., -0.64439666]])                         

 B = array([[-0 , -0.28733533, -0.],
            [-0 , -2.12692801, -0]])

sum(A + B)

array([-0.57654415, -2.41426334, -3.88434999])
```

Why does it result in a 1-D array?

Comment: please clean up the provided code

Comment: the `+` would have been enough i think. but you called a `sum` on the result again, which collapsed the array by adding each row or whatnot. Can't know for sure because the snippet you provided can't be run as-is.

Comment: `Y*np.log(A) = ...` is not valid python code

Comment: Do `sum(Y*np.log(A) , (1-Y)*np.log(1-A)) ` instead

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [numpy.add](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy-add)

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([[-0.31326169, -0., -3.23995333],[-0.26328247, -0., -0.64439666]])
arr2 = np.array([[-0., -0.28733533, -0.],[-0., -2.12692801, -0.]])
arr3=np.add(arr1,arr2)
print(arr3)
```

Output

```
[[-0.31326169 -0.28733533 -3.23995333]
 [-0.26328247 -2.12692801 -0.64439666]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `A + B` is a 2 by 3 array, and it's then summed using the built-in `sum` function (`np.sum` would've returned a single number).

`__builtins__.sum` will iterate over the given array, and the iteration happens to be row-wise, so individual rows will be added up (I called your arrays `X` and `Y`):

```
>>> X + Y
array([[-0.31326169, -0.28733533, -3.23995333],
       [-0.26328247, -2.12692801, -0.64439666]])
```

Then, `sum(X + Y)` will do the following:

```
__sum = 0
for row in (X + Y):
    __sum += row

return __sum
```

So, individual rows will be summed:

```
>>> X + Y
array([[-0.31326169, -0.28733533, -3.23995333],
       [-0.26328247, -2.12692801, -0.64439666]])
>>> _[0] + _[1]
array([-0.57654416, -2.41426334, -3.88434999])
```

If you want to sum `X` and `Y` element-wise, then... just sum them: `result = X + Y`.